# Loading images from github

Tags: image, github

I have used the github API to display the repos I want dynamically with react and got all the information I want except for an image for each project..

I tried uploading the image and reading the README but that didn't work and tried a few other things but to no avail.. It seems that github isn't very image friendly.

What would be the best way to link one image to each github repo dynamically? It's important that it would be dynamic.

Comment: can you clarify a bit? you're trying to render the readme? converting the markdown to HTML?

Comment: Sure. 
1) So i am pulling all my github repository from the github API.
2)I need an image that matches every repo to display on my website. therefore what would be a good approach for this?
I have tried many things but none have worked.

Comment: you can always access raw images if you repo is served as a GitHub page (since it's served as static files) or use a raw github url like: https://github.com/Kibibit/kibibit-assets/raw/master/logo-achi.png (this points to a file on the root of the master branch). I usually have a logo.png image in the root of every repo so I can reference it without worrying about file names and things like that.

Comment: Thanks, i used your idea to some extent although it's not great for a dynamic solution, really wish you could access Github social image for each repo via their API.